# Gwt Listbox item reference to an Object

Tags: java, object, gwt, listbox

I have got a Listbox and i want to add some Items.
There are only methods to add items as a String, but
I want add a Item to the Listbox with a String and a reference to an Object.
So that, if a item was selected in the Listbox, I get the Object reference too.
Otherwise I have always to search with equal for the right Object.

Is there any option therefore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the object in a Map indexed by the value of the item, or in an array or List, at the index of the added item in the list box.

Comment: At the moment I have got a Vector<myObjects> of Objects.
Now I want to add them a ListBox.

Comment: If you keep the vector in parallel to your listbox, you may get the object at index i in the vector when the item at index i is selected in the listbox.

Comment: sry I posted too fast ;)

At the moment I have got a Vector<myObjects> of Objects.
Now I want to add them to the ListBox.
When something was selected at the ListBox, I want to get the Object and not a String.
Something like: mylistbox.add(String name, MyObject myObject).

Or do you mean something like this:
int i = myListbox.getSelectedItem();
Myobject object = MyObjectVector.elementAt(i)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 8):

Try [`ValueListBox`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueListBox.html) instead of `ListBox`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but since the most elegant answer is not yet here:

```
// Applicable for an object of specified type 'User'
ValueListBox<User> lbUser = new ValueListBox<User>(new Renderer<User>() {

  public String render(User user) {
    String s = "";
    if (user != null) {
      // Specify the format for the Strings to display per list item here. In this example, it is 
      // 'username (firstname lastname)'
      // For example: MTielemans (Mark Tielemans)
      s = user.getUsername() + "("+user.getFirstname()+" " + user.getLastname()+")";
    } else {
      s = "Select a user";
    }
    return s; 
  }

  public void render(User user, Appendable appendable) throws IOException {
      String s = render(user);
      appendable.append(s);
  }
});
```