# How do I reference a ListBox item

Tags: powershell, winforms, powershell-5.1

Sometimes things (PowerShell?) gets *too* smart on me...

In this case, I would like change the `Text` property of a WinForms [`ListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox) item selected by its index (*not the [`SelectedItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems)*). The point here is that `$ListBox.Items[$CurrentIndex]` appears to be a `[string]` type rather than an [`[Item]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.item) type...
For this I have created a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (with a context menu) out of my bigger project:

```
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
$Form = [Form]@{ StartPosition = 'CenterScreen' }
$ListBox = [ListBox]@{}
@('one', 'two', 'three').ForEach{ $Null = $ListBox.Items.Add($_) }
$Form.Controls.Add($ListBox)
$ListBox.ContextMenuStrip = [ContextMenuStrip]@{}
$Context = $ListBox.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add('ToUpper')
$ListBox.Add_MouseDown({ param($s, $e) 
    if ($e.Button -eq 'Right') { $Script:CurrentIndex = $ListBox.IndexFromPoint($e.Location) }
})
$Context.Add_Click({ param($s, $e)
    if ($Null -ne $CurrentIndex) {
        $Text = $ListBox.Items[$CurrentIndex]
        Write-Host "I want to change text ""$Text"" of the item #$CurrentIndex to: ""$($Text.ToUpper())"""
        # $ListBox.Items.Item[$CurrentIndex] = $Text.ToUpper()
    }
})
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

How can I change the text of e.g. `$ListBox.Items[1]` ("`two`") to e.g. "`TWO`"?
<strike><sub>I am actually not sure whether this is PowerShell related issue (similar to [`#16878` Decorate dot selected `Xml` strings (leaves) with `XmlElement` methods](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16878) where I would have an option to use the `SelectNodes()` method) or related to WinForms itself: The answer might be in [Gwt Listbox item reference to an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6655612/1701026) in which case I have no clue how translate this to PowerShell.</sub></strike>

Comment: That's odd, `$ListBox.Items[$CurrentIndex]` gets updated with the new value just that the form is not showing the update

Comment: Refresh semantics of some form controls are just plain weird when you manually edit the item collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* modify the stored item value with `$ListBox.Items.Item($CurrentIndex) = $Text.ToUpper()` - but modifying a collection item in place is not going to trigger re-drawing the `ListBox` control, so it'll look like no change took place.

Instead, modify the collection itself - remove the old entry and insert a new one at the same position:

```
$Context.Add_Click({ param($s, $e)
    if ($Null -ne $CurrentIndex) {
        $Text = $ListBox.Items[$CurrentIndex]
        # Remove clicked item
        $ListBox.Items.RemoveAt($CurrentIndex)
        # Insert uppercased string value as new item at the same index
        $ListBox.Items.Insert($CurrentIndex, $Text.ToUpper())
    }
})
```

This will cause the owning control to refresh and the change will be reflected in the GUI immediately

Comment: Thanks both for your insights and fixes. As mentioned by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), both workarounds have their (dis)advantages. In this solution, reinserting the item causes the **selection state** to be lost (as in the other solution, it looses **the scroll state**). This can be worked around by capturing the state (`$Selected = $ListBox.GetSelected($CurrentIndex)`) and reapplying it: (`$ListBox.SetSelected($CurrentIndex, $Selected)`) after the reinsert.

Comment: @iRon, you may not always see it, but deleting and re-adding can change the scroll state too, so you must save and restore `.TopIndex` as well. If either of you has any insight into why  item-specific refreshing  doesn't work, i.e. why calling `.ResetItem($CurrentIndex)` on a `BindingList[string]` instance serving as the `.DataSource` has no effect, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71237925/45375):

Indeed, the problem isn't with the modification of the `.Items` collection itself - `$ListBox.Items[$CurrentIndex] = $Text.ToUpper()` works just fine.<sup>[1]</sup>

To address the real problem - the `ListBox` not refreshing in response to modifying *an existing item* in the underlying `.Items` collection *in place* (not even if you call `$ListBox.Refresh()`), there's an alternative to removing and re-adding the item:

You can use *data binding*, by assigning a [`` System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.ComponentModel.BindingList-1) instance to the list box's `.DataSource` property.

After modifying an item in place, you can call the [`.ResetBindings()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.ComponentModel.BindingList-1.ResetBindings) method to get the listbox to refresh itself, as shown below.

Note:

- There's also a [`.ResetItem(int index)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.ComponentModel.BindingList-1.ResetItem) method designed to perform *item-specific* refreshing, but I couldn't get it to work; pointers as to why are appreciated.
- `.ResetBindings()` can change the scrolling state of the listbox, which is why the code below saves and restores it explicitly. It does, however, automatically retain the *selection status* of the listbox (which the deleting-and-re-adding approach would have to manage manually too).

```sh
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.ComponentModel

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = [Form]@{ StartPosition = 'CenterScreen' }
$ListBox = [ListBox]@{}

# Define the items as a strongly typed array of item strings.
[string[]] $items = @('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight')
# Wrap the array in a [BindingList[string]] instance
# and make it the listbox's data source.
$ListBox.DataSource = [BindingList[string]]::new($items)

$Form.Controls.Add($ListBox)
$ListBox.ContextMenuStrip = [ContextMenuStrip]@{}
$Context = $ListBox.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add('ToUpper')
$ListBox.Add_MouseDown({ param($s, $e) 
    if ($e.Button -eq 'Right') { $Script:CurrentIndex = $ListBox.IndexFromPoint($e.Location) }
})
$Context.Add_Click({ param($s, $e)
    if ($null -ne $CurrentIndex) {
        # Modify the underlying array.
        $items[$CurrentIndex] = $items[$CurrentIndex].ToUpper()
        # To prevent unwanted scrolling during the refresh below, 
        # save and restore what item is currently shown at the top 
        # of the visible list portion.
        $prevTopIndex = $ListBox.TopIndex 
        # Notify the listbox via the BindingList[string] instance that
        # the items have changed.
        # !! The following *item-specific* call does NOT work.
        # !!   $ListBox.DataSource.ResetItem($CurrentIndex)
        $ListBox.DataSource.ResetBindings()
        $ListBox.TopIndex = $prevTopIndex # Restore the scrolling state.
    }
})
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

---

<sup>[1]
A general *syntax observation*: The verbose alternative is to *explicitly* call the `.Item` method that implements the *parameterized property* that provides index-based access: `$ListBox.Items.Item($CurrentIndex)`. This applies to any `IList`-implementing collection type, including arrays. However, there is generally no need for this, given that PowerShell surfaces such parameterized properties via *direct indexing*. E.g., given an array `$a = 'foo', 'bar'`, `$a.Item(1)` is more naturally expressed as `$a[1]`</sup>